# TouchAction methods did not work for my mobile tests

Tags: selenium, appium

I have a UI slider component. On clicking the knob I can drag the slider left and right. 
I need to test this functionality on mobile. I am using iOS and android simulators using saucelabs.

I tried the below code :

```
    slider = appium.findElement(By.id("numInput"));
    int xStart = slider.getLocation().getX();
    int yStart = slider.getLocation().getY();
    int end= xStart + slider.getSize().getWidth();

    System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("aria-valuenow"));

    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(appium);
    int moveTo=(int)(end*0.1);
    action.longPress(xStart,yStart).moveTo(moveTo,yStart).perform();
    System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("aria-valuenow"));
```

But an error is encountered :
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException : Method is not implemented.
at line : action.longPress(xStart,yStart).moveTo(moveTo,yStart).perform();

Then I did some research and found that I need to switch to Native_App to get it working

But when I switch to Native App :

```
    slider = appium.findElement(By.id("numInput"));
    int xStart = slider.getLocation().getX();
    int yStart = slider.getLocation().getY();
    int end= xStart + slider.getSize().getWidth();

    System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("aria-valuenow"));//slider val
    String originalContext = appium.getContext();
    appium.context("NATIVE_APP");
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(appium);
    int moveTo=(int)(end*0.1);
    action.longPress(xStart,yStart).moveTo(moveTo,yStart).perform();
    System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("aria-valuenow"));
```

Another error : System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("aria-valuenow"));
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Also the slider does not move.

Capabilities:

```
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,iPhone 6 Plus Simulator);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, 9.3);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,Safari);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, 1.5.3)
    if (appiumDriver.equalsIgnoreCase("iOS")) {
                appium = new IOSDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
     } else if (appiumDriver.equalsIgnoreCase("android")) {
                appium = new AndroidDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
     }
```

Comment: The second error is likely due to you not being able to find the element `slider`. Could you debug your code to the line the error is on and check if `slider = null`

Comment: So I debugged my code. And I found that the browser shuts down immediately after action.longPress(xStart,yStart).moveTo(moveTo,yStart).perform();
Therefore when I find an element, it is not present. Do happen to know why does this happen? @JaysonP

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TouchAction, you can use **swipe** method.

```
driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 500);
```

Comment: This does not work for me. If I use swipe method without doing a context switch to Native_App.

Comment: It throws an error : Method not implemented 

So I do a context switch.
But then the WebElement is not found.org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me, you can give it a try, touchShortcuts actually do the magic here.

((TouchShortcuts) driver).swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 500);